# Install server on Azure website

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-applications

I would like to install a web application on a Azure Website (not virtual machine). I do have a directory  which contains the asp.net/c# application. The documentation only says the following:

"To install the server, simply create a new web application in IIS (or in the shared hosting control panel), pointing to a folder in which you copy the contents of the supplied folder"

Sounds easy but I don't even know where to start. Can you give me a hint? Do I have to use Visual Studio to get it working? What I found on the internet suggest this but I think the folder contains already the "output" of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install a server, it's already done for you with Azure Websites.

There are many ways to deploy and app: Dropbox, FTP, Visual Studio, etc.

Correct me if I'm wrong but my guess is that you're not familiar with Visual Studio and you're looking for an easy way to deploy your app.  If so, I would look at Dropbox.  Check this Channel9 video explaining how to do it:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Dropbox-Deployment-to-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I want to install is not a web server but some kind of content server. I think better to speak of a web application here. I also managed to open an ftp connection to the Azure server, so putting an index.html file there should give me a website. I think your Dropbox Link does more or less the same what I can do via ftp. My main problem is: What should I do with the application files I have? Where do I need to copy them and how can I then access/start the web application?